# Opam publish fails due to wget retrieval failure (404)

Tags: git, module, ocaml, publish, opam

Simply put, I have a library with a module. I can install it locally with `opam install .` in the local version of the GitHub repository without issue and use it just fine.

Following the instructions [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Packaging.html), I created the corresponding `.opam` file, tested it using `opam install .` and tried using it via `dune`, and tagged and pushed the archive.

However, when I try to run `opam publish`, I get the following error:

```sh
[ERROR] Uncaught exception: OpamDownload.Download_fail(_, "Download command failed: \"/usr/local/bin/wget --content-disposition -t 3 -O
        /private/var/folders/zj/jsz2c_2x4blgtf_b14lfwl3r0000gn/T/opam-29567-5a61c5/archives/790f017e8273931983fa69cb4a5b6951-1.0.tar.gz.part https://github.com/[redacted]/[packageName]/archive/1.0.tar.gz -U opam/2.0.7\" exited with code 8
        \"2020-12-18 01:52:47 ERROR 404: Not Found.\"")
```

Here are the versions of various potentially-related packages:

- `wget`: GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on darwin18.7.0.
- `opam`: 2.0.7
- `dune`: 2.7.1
- `git`: git version 2.29.2
- `opam-publish`: 2.0.2
- `gpatch`: 2.7.6

Here is how my `.opam` file generally looks with some redactions as necessary:

```
opam-version: "2.0"
name: "example"
version: "1.0"
synopsis: "This is essentially what my .opam file looks like but with the text redacted"
description: """
packageExample is a framework that is used for the sole purpose of being an example. It
does not actually do anything, and it in fact does not even really exist. All that
references this framework is this example representation of it in this .opam file.
"""
maintainer: "[Redacted] <[redacted@gmail.com]>"
authors: "[Redacted] <[redacted]@gmail.com>"
homepage: "https://github.com/[redacted]/example"
dev-repo: "git+https://github.com/[redacted]/example.git"
bug-reports: "https://github.com/[redacted]/example/issues"
doc: "[redacted]"
depends: [
    "ocaml" {>= "4.08.1"}
    "dune" {>= "2.7.1"}
    "base-bytes"
    "base-unix"
]
build: [
    ["dune" "build" "-p" name "-j" jobs]
    ["dune" "runtest" "-p" name "-j" jobs] {with-test}
    ["dune" "build" "@doc" "-p" name "-j" jobs] {with-doc}
]
```

Comment: Did you create an issue directly on the opam github page?

Comment: @Lhooq Someone I know did, yes. Still waiting there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the GitHub repository must be public for `opam publish` to work. Go figure.

Also, the autogeneration of the token failed for some reason, so I had to manually generate one from https://github.com/settings/tokens and provide it.